# Trying to override to_s

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie to Ruby and I don't understand why do I have the result that I have.

- I have a `Person` class in which I have the instance variables, `@name`,
  `@age` and `@weight`. In this class I override the to_s method to print
  the `@name`, `@age` and `@weight` of the object.
- I have a House class in which I have an array of objects of type
  `Person` (`@persons`), and also I have a method called `person` that
  returns an object (in the position that is specified with the
  parameter number) in the array `@persons`, so for example, `any_house_object.person(0)`
  will return the first object of the array of objects of type `Person` that is on the `any_house_object` object.

  ```
  class Person
      def initialize(name, age, weight)
          @name = name
          @age = age
          @weight = weight
      end

      def to_s
          puts "Name: #{@name}"
          puts "Age: #{@age}"
          puts "Weight: #{@weight}"
      end
  end

  class House
      def initialize
          @persons = []
      end

      def add_person(name, age, weight)
          @persons << Person.new(name, age, weight)
      end

      def person(number)
          @persons[number]
      end
  end

  my_house = House.new

  my_house.add_person("Patrick", "18", "65")
  my_house.add_person("John", "18", "65")

  puts my_house.person(0)
  ```

This produce

```
    Name: Patrick
    Age: 18
    Wight: 65
    #<Person:0x5e2318>
```

**Finally, my problem is that I don't understand why at the end, when I do `puts my_house.person(0)` also appears `#<Person:0x5e2318>` at the end.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`to_s` is supposed to *return* a string, not output a string to the console. Your method needs to return the string you're building:

```
def to_s
  "Name: #{@name}\nAge: #{@age}\nWeight: #{@weight}"
end
```

Secondly, `to_s` is for converting an object to a string. You're not actually *doing* that anywhere. Just invoking `puts <object>` doesn't have anything to do with `to_s`.

If you want to output the string representation of your object, you either need...

```
puts my_house.person(0).to_s
```

Or, you need to also define a custom `inspect` method and use `p <object>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I did a pretty stupid mistake